# C++ a reference of type "std::ostream &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::ofstream"

Tags: c++

I have this section of code:

```
std::ofstream RBXMX_Out;
std::string RBXMX_FileName;
```

Whenever I try to compile, I always get this error:

```
RBXMX_Out = std::ofstream(RBXMX_FileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
```

Since there's no answers to be found on Google, I wanted to ask the Stack Overflow community, now, I have included this headers:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Scanner.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

- Scanner.h is only a memory scanning header file, and does not have any errors in it.

Comment: STL streams can't be copied, so using `operator=` does not work. You need to pass the filename and flags to the constructor: `std::ofstream RBXMX_Out(RBXMX_FileName, std::ios_base::binary);`, or to the `open()` method: `RBXMX_Out.open(RBXMX_FileName, std::ios_base::binary);`

Comment: Why can't you declare `RBXMX_Out` as a `std::ofstream`? Why the funny business?

Comment: @RemyLebeau the example still does not work, it says incomplete type is not allowed, another error that i got: left of '.open' must have class/struct/union

Comment: You must `#include <fstream>`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: They can be moved though, so `operator=` should work fine if the rhs is an r-value (and the compiler is compiling in C++11 or later mode), which it is in this case.

Comment: @AmitBashan examples are in my comment

Comment: @StoryTeller look again, it IS declared as `std::ofstream`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - It wasn't. The OP may very well have edited in the grace period. I didn't comment frivolously, I know what I saw. And the title still contains a remnant of that.